# Patch/Put/Update API call in Eber.js

Tags: ember.js, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask restless to run the api endpoints and requests like:

```
$.post('http://localhost:5000/api/expense', item);

$.get('http://localhost:5000/api/person')
```

are working fine. Now I want to make a patch or put API call so tried:

```
$.put('http://localhost:5000/api/expense/id', item)
```

Also tried:

```
$.patch('http://localhost:5000/api/expense/id', item)
```

But it is not working. Error is $.put is not a function.

Can you please specify the format for making this call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually using to make your requests is jQuery. jQuery only offers shorthand methods for GET and POST requests. If you want to make a put requests you have to use the ajax method and set the method to `PUT`.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/expense/id',
  data: item
});
```